# add multiple input lines and add it to fetch method with reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, input

I want to add some input lines by a click of a button and add it to state so I can send it to the server, but I'm not sure how to add it to the fetch method or even if it's added to state,

this is what i have so far:

```
export class AdminPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { 
          sendeEmail: '',
          matrialeliste: [{
          matrialer: '',
          antal: '',
          pris: ''}]
        };
      }
      handleUserInput = (e) => {
        if (["matrialer", "antal", "pris"].includes(e.target.className) ) {
          let matrialeliste = [...this.state.matrialeliste]
          //matrialeliste[e.target.dataset.id][e.target.className] = e.target.value
          this.setState({ matrialeliste }, () => console.log(this.state.matrialeliste))
        } else {
          const name = e.target.name;
          const value = e.target.value;
          this.setState({[name]: value};
        }
      }
      addMatrialeliste = (e) => {
        this.setState((prevState) => ({
          matrialeliste: [...prevState.matrialeliste, {matrialer:"", antal:"", pris:""}],
        }));
      }
      onSubmitSignIn = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

            fetch(`${api.url}/form`, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    sendeEmail: this.state.sendeEmail,          
                })
            })
            .then((response) => (response.json()))
            .catch(error => console.log(error));
    }

      render(){
        let {matrialeliste} = this.state;
          return(

            <div>
              <div>
                <h1>Arbejds seddel</h1>
                <form>

                    <div>
                      <button type="button" onClick={this.addMatrialeliste}>
                            tilføj materialer
                          </button>
                    {
                      matrialeliste.map((val, idx) => {

                        return(
                      <div key={idx}>
                      <div>
                        <label htmlFor="matrialer">
                            Matrialeliste
                          </label>
                          <input name='matrialer' type="text" className='matrialer' onChange={this.handleUserInput} />
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        <label htmlFor="antal">
                            Antal
                          </label>
                          <input name='antal' type="number" className='antal' onChange={this.handleUserInput} />
                      </div>

                      <div>
                        <label htmlFor="pris">
                            Pris
                          </label>
                          <input name='pris' type="number" className='pris' onChange={this.handleUserInput} />
                      </div>

                    </div>)})}
                    <label htmlFor="email">
                            E-mail
                          </label>
                    <input name='email' type="email" onChange={e => this.handleUserInput} />
                      <button type="submit">Send som E-mail</button>

                  <div>
                   <button type="submit" disabled=this.state.formValid}>Create</button>
                  </div>
                  </div>
                </form>
              </div>
          </div>
          );
      }
}
```

I can get to add extra lines, but I don't know how to add it to the fetch method.

I was thinking I could map it, but I'm still unsure how do that

Comment: What do you mean by input lines? Any concrete example?

Comment: something like <input type="text" />

Comment: Do you want to pass the whole state to fetch method or just `sendeEmail`?

Answer (score 0):

Creating forms with plain React requires you to write each part of the process and for a complex state its become tough .so, my personal opinion is to go with [Formik](https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/overview) or [React Hook Form](https://react-hook-form.com/) as they cover most of the features.

In your case, I am assuming you want to sent whole state to fetch method .here is an [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/awesome-worker-bgg2q?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark) of your code which implemented with Formik library.

Comment: Okay I can add more lines to the list but when I send it I get an 500 (Internal Server Error) and the server works with postman

Comment: Internal Server Error is from backend api, check your API or put here as a question.